# How to change options in a select list, based on the selected option of a previous select list?

Tags: javascript, html

How to change options in a select list, based on the selected option of a previous select list?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/32198-change-options-select-based-selection-other-select.html) tread.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do dynamic like this via simple html. You should use javascript for example. In google there are a lot of solutions, this is one of them:
http://programmersforum.ru/showpost.php?p=227550&postcount=3

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

For example:

```
var categoryItems = {
    'Car':             [ 'Acura', 'Honda', 'Toyota' ],
    'Computer:         [ 'Dell', 'HP', 'Lenovo' ],
    'Search engine':   [ 'Google', 'Bing', 'Yahoo' ]
};
$('#category').change(function() {
    var itemsDropdown = $('#items').empty();
    var items = categoryItems[$(this).val()];
    for(var i = 0;  < items.length; i++)
        itemsDropdown.append($('<option />').text(items[i]));
});
```

Comment: How would I go about doing it? I have a list of locations, and when a location is selected I want to show a list of regions within that location.

Comment: Which ID's are #category and #items referring to? and where would I put that javascript?

Comment: The IDs of the two dropdown lists.  You would put this in a `$(function() { ... });` call in a `<script>` block.

Comment: Hmm I'm still not there, could you possibly post an example including some html?

Comment: I will not write all of your code for you.  You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: I was not after you to do it for me, I merely wanted to see how to implement it, so I could learn. But nevermind, thanks anyway.